# solving simultaneous congruence equation involving exponents

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to the solve following congruence equations efficiently

$x \equiv k\pmod p$
$a^{x} \equiv k^{-1}*b\pmod p  $

where $a$ , $k$ , $b$ are constants and $p$ is a prime number less than $10^{6}$ and $1<a,b<p$

I tried it by first finding smallest $x$ from first equation and iterating for all $x$ less than $p*(p-1)$ such that $a^{x} \equiv k^{-1}*b\pmod p  $.But as you can see $p <= 10^{6}$ so $p*(p-1)$ < $10^{12}$.so this is not efficient.So please give any other idea.Thank you.

Comment: You can solve the second congruence to get a value for $x\pmod {p-1}$.  Then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get $x\pmod {p(p-1)}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that in an answer as I am a newbie in number theory

Comment: Exponential congruences can be difficult to work with.  $10^6$ is quite small, so in this case you can do a brute force search, though I expect it is more efficient to discover the order of $a\pmod p$, which has to be a divisor of $p-1$.  If you are unfamiliar with computations using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I'd suggest starting there.  Those come up constantly.

Comment: @lulu a and b are always less than p.I have edited the question.I think I am starting to understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Doesn't matter that $a,b$ are less than $p$. Doesn't even have meaning, really, since you are just working with congruences $\pmod p$.  Start by solving the problem by hand, for small $p$...try $p=101$ or something.  That already contains all the math you need.  Note:  the exponential congruence doesn't have to have any solutions at all.

Comment: Thanks @lulu.I got it.